# Рецепты ifttt, или что нужно для связи Гугл таблицы с Гугл календарем

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет. Задача у меня такая. При заполнении формы в Гугл, создаётся строка в Гугл таблице. Каким способом можно эту информацию из таблицы, а именно новую дату, автоматически закинуть в Гугл календарь, (чтобы в дальнейшем было напоминание)?
Наткнулся на сервис "ifttt" (telegram-bot), который может внедряться куда нужно, и делать какие-то действия. Есть кто уже пользовался этим сервисом?Можно решить мою задачу с его помощью? Или какой другой способ порекомендуете?

Comment: IFTTT не позволяет в качестве источника события использовать Google Drive :/ Кстати, непонятно, почему с главной перебрасывает сразу на страницу телеграм-бота, вообще, оно умеет работать не только через него: https://ifttt.com/create/if?sid=0

Comment: А что в таком случае можете порекомендовать?

Comment: Может мою задачу выполнить скрипт встраиваемый в гугл док? так чтобы это происходило автоматически? без отдельного запуска скрипта?